# NodeJS: download CSV with multiple data tables

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm currently using `objects-to-csv` package to download data in CSV, seems like this package is missing a feature to spread data across different tables instead of putting everything in one.

Here is my code if that helps at all, but my main question is if there any other method to do that?

```
const objectstocsv = require("objects-to-csv");
const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const forumData = await getForumData();
  const redditData = await getRedditData();
  const allData = forumData.concat(redditData)

  const csv = new objectstocsv(allData) <== Puts it all into one table
  console.log(csv, "testing result")
  // Save to file:
  await csv.toDisk("./test.csv", { allColumns: true });

  res.download("./test.csv", () => {
    fs.unlinkSync("./test.csv");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [typical format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#page-2) for CSV files is one table per file. I'm not sure how you're trying to combine two possibly different record layouts into a single CSV file.

Another option is to output two CSV files:

```
const forumData = await getForumData();
const redditData = await getRedditData();

const csvForum = new ObjectsToCsv(forumData);
const csvReddit = new ObjectsToCsv(redditData);

// Save to file:
csvForum.toDisk('./forum.csv', { allColumns: true });
csvReddit.toDisk('./reddit.csv', { allColumns: true });
```

Then you could combine the CSV files however way you want.